# no such file to load -- initializer (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have following installed on ubuntu 12

- ruby 1.9.2p320
- Rails 3.2.6

Now I have old project which is developed into Rails 2 & Ruby 1.8.7

**Problem:**

When i run below command under old project root directory

```
ruby ./script/plugin install git://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade.git
```

Following error comes

```
Invalid gemspec in [/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/specifications/ZenTest-4.9.1.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["< 2.1, >= 1.8"]
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require': no such file to load -- initializer (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /var/www/project/client/softwallet/config/boot.rb:54:in `load_initializer'
        from /var/www/project/client/softwallet/config/boot.rb:38:in `run'
        from /var/www/project/client/softwallet/config/boot.rb:11:in `boot!'
        from /var/www/project/client/softwallet/config/boot.rb:109:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from ./script/plugin:2:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Use `rvm`. So when you work with old project change the ruby version to old by `rvm use 1.8.7` and if you work with new project then use `rvm use 1.9.2`. This will eliminate any incompatibility issues.

Comment: But i want to upgrade rails 2 project to rails 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading the old rails project to new one and getting the `invalid gemspec` problem.

Then you have to do the following:

Run `gem update --system` followed by `bundle install`.

**UPDATE:**

You are using the same old `config/boot.rb` from your older version of rails application.

Do the following:

1) Create a new project directory.

2) Generate a new rails app (Of your new latest rails version)

3) Use `boot.rb` that is created by it.

Comment: Thanks! but how to resolve this `no such file to load -- initializer (LoadError)`

Comment: Do i need to copy new `boot.rb` file to old project and then run ?

Comment: yes that is what you have to do. Basically there are much differences in `routes` for old and new versions too together with `environment.rb` changes. So you may also require to change `routes.rb` and `environment.rb` at some point of time to get it to work completely.

Comment: See the routes differences for rails 2 and rails 3 here: http://blog.engineyard.com/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3

Comment: now i am getting `require': no such file to load -- commands/plugin (LoadError)
`

Comment: You should  use the new syntax to install the plugin: `rails plugin install git://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade.git`

or

`ruby script/rails plugin install 
git://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade.git`. The one you are using is for rails 2 version and will not work for rails 3.

Comment: Ok then i am getting `ruby: No such file or directory -- script/rails (LoadError)
`

Comment: copy everything from the script folder of your new rails app into
script folder of your old rails app. Then try installing the plugin again with the command I just commented out.

Comment: now i am getting `require': no such file to load -- gbarcode (LoadError)`

Comment: this is because you have you `gem gbarcode` in the gemfile. See your gemfile and check the branch or git its using there.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have incompatible version of the same gem already installed on your environment.
To rectify, either you can uninstall and reinstall the gem or install the gem of the specific version.

Make sure that you do a gem cleanup operation before doing so.

Comment: your solution related to `Invalid gemspec` or `no such file to load -- initializer (LoadError)`

Answer (score 0):

This is how my problem was solved . I was using RVM and if you have edited those .bashrc files then each time while you log in to the shell , do a **/bin/bash --login** . What this does is , it makes the command line take note of the rvm path you had set and installs them first .

I did this on Ubuntu 12 and it did solve my issue , i don't think doing gem update --system is a good idea as it really kind of messes up the environment forcing one to do an rvm implode and install it all over again .